# TMD auto create

Tags: mysql, temporary-tables

I used mysql as part of a project and found it to be a very practical tool.

I have a question about mysql in regards to how it creates temporary table types TMD in `/var/lib/mysql/`. This partition takes as much memory as the original table!

I do not know what mechanism creates a table automatically, but I'd like this feature to be disabled, or at least configure mysql to put the temporary tables in `/tmp`, not `/var/lib/mysql`.